# PHP odbc_connect to Pervasive SQL 2000i returning text strings max 10 characters

Tags: php, sql, odbc, pervasive-sql

I am working for a company who bought DBA Manufacturing and I need to retrieve some values from the Pervasive SQL 2000i DB. Unfortunately there are no plans to upgrade the DB so I have to make due with what I have. I am running a 32 bit

I was able to make an `odbc_connect` call in PHP to the DSN on a windows machine. I am running PHP on Windows with NGINX.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Placeholder Title
</title>
</head>    
<body>

<?php

// mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

// connect to the dbamfg DSN
$connect=odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=dbamfg.1583;ServerDSN=dbadefault;","",""); 

// query the users table for name and surname
$query = "select * from BKARINVL where BKAR_INVL_INVNM = 600100 order by bkar_invl_cntr ";

//Prepare the statement
$result = odbc_prepare ($connect, $query);
// execute the query
odbc_execute($result);

// fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){

  $SalesOrder = odbc_result($result, 1);
  $InvLine = odbc_result($result, 2);
  $EstShpDt = odbc_result($result, 3);
  $ProdCode = odbc_result($result, 4);
  $ProdDesc = odbc_result($result, 5);

  echo ('<br />'.$InvLine.'<br />'); 
  echo ($SalesOrder.'<br />'); 
  echo ($EstShpDt.'<br />'); 
  echo ($ProdCode.'<br />'); 
  echo ($ProdDesc.'<br />'); 

}

// closing the connection
odbc_close($connect);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The query returns numeric values just fine. When it comes to text columns it returns 10 characters and after that it shows characters that are not displaying correctly.

here is an example:

```
1
600100
2015-05-31
020-0015-1
DIGITAL VI!2S��

2
600100
2015-05-31
020-0012-0
2 X 4 AUDI!5S��

3
600100
2015-05-31
020-0065-0
16-CKT LOW!8S��
```

I'm excited and shocked that I have gotten this far! It's exceptionally fast to retrieve values from Pervasive through the ODBC connection and I feel like I am very close to being successful. I just need a push in the right direction.

Everything I have tried so far: I have tried to set the internal encoding of the page to several different character sets including UTF-8, Windows, ASCII, etc. I have also tried to select the checkbox under the ODBC driver setup options during DSN setup in Windows, which says "Use OEM/ANSI Conversion". This does nothing but change the characters by a bit.

Another clue to this is that for some reason when I call the connection string using `System.Data.odbc` in C# it returns the query and text values in full.

I have tried using `iconv` to convert the values to UTF-8, etc., to no avail. I've tried forcing the header to display the page in different character sets. I have tried `mb_detect_encoding()` on the `odbc_result()` and the return value says UTF-8, but I assume it has to do  There must be someone out there that knows how to fix this. Please, would anyone point me in the right direction? I will be forever grateful!

If anything more needs to be added to solve this I will include it when requested. Thank you!